# Using a module with variable name in Python

Tags: python, python-module

I want to run a function of a module with a variable name for example:

`Plugins.SomeUnknownName.function()` without knowing their name but `Plugins.` and `.function()` stay the same.

I have tried several things like `plugin = 'Plugins.' + unknown_plugin_name + '.function()'` or

```
plugin_name = "SomePlugin"

Plugins.plugin_name.function()
```

But I don't know any further.

Maybe someone knows how to solve that.

Also this is my first stack overflow post, so please correct me if I did something wrong.

Comment: What about `getattr(Plugins, plugin_name).function()` (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getattr` to pass the string name. Using `numpy` as an example here's what the normal usage would look like

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.random.randint(1, 5)
2
```

Now similar to your example

```
>>> getattr(numpy, 'random').randint(1, 5)
2
```

So applying to your case

```
getattr(Plugins, 'plugin_name').function()
```